# RVM not changing loaded ruby

Tags: rvm

I have an .rvmrc file:

```
rvm use 1.9.3-p286@refinery --create
```

and changing to that folder yields:

```
Using /Users/neil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286 with gemset refinery
$ ~/code/visioneng/ master* ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
$ ~/code/visioneng/ master*
```

However, this clearly isn't what I asked for.  What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if you do not overwrite `PATH` in any of your shell scripts/functions/aliases